# How to view one characters on absolute galois of a number field $F$ as an ideal group character?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations

Suppose I start with a number field $F$ and a character $$ \chi :G_F =\operatorname{Gal}(\overline F/F)\rightarrow {\overline {\mathbf Q}}^\times.  $$
How does one get a character on ideals of $F$? What does conductor being $\mathfrak n$ mean?
I know that $\chi $ factors through some finite Galois extension $H$.
A guess of mine is that define $\chi (\mathfrak p)= \chi (\operatorname{Frob}_\mathfrak p )$ and conductor is product of all the primes that ramify in $H$ so $\chi $ of these primes is anyway $0$.

I was also given to understand that if $F$ is totally real then $H/F$ is cyclic. Why is this so?

Any help is appreciated, feel free to give any reference for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $\chi$ factors over through the abelianization $G_F^{ab}$, let the induced character on $G_F^{ab}$ also be denoted by $\chi$. We have by idelic global class field theory, a surjective continuous homomorphism from the idele class group $C_K \to G_F^{ab}$. (This is an inverse limit of Artin maps). Thus composing with this surjective homomorphism, we obtain a character of $C_K$, i.e. a Hecke character.

Comment: It's also possible to do this just with ideals, but I find the idelic framework to be more elegant.

Comment: thanks. So my guess of the map seems to be correct. I guess we may not get a class group character but after descending to a finite extension $H$ we can get a ray class character since we have the Artin map from the ray class group with the defining modulus of $H$.   Can you clarify what is the conductor? Also, do you know why $H$ can be assumed to be cyclic when $F$ is totally real?

Comment: @mathemather The definition of the Artin conductor is a bit complicated, but there's a [wikipedia entry on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin_conductor). In the case of 1-dimensional representations, though, it is equal to the conductor of the associated Hecke character.

I'm confused by the condition that $F$ is totally real. Can't we _always_ assume that $H$ is cyclic over $F$? The image of $\chi$ is a finite subgroup of a field hence cyclic, so the kernel corresponds by infinite Galois theory to a cyclic extension of $F$.

Comment: you are right. I didn't make that observation. $F$ being totally real has nothing to do with that.